# Calling a virtual function: compare base versus derived reference calls?

Tags: c++, gcc, polymorphism

Given a base class B with a virtual function f, a derived class D and it's own implementation of f here are my scenarios:

1. `B& b = *new D; b.f();`
2. `D& d = *new D; d.f();`

Does the code in bullet 1 involve fetching f's address from vtable and then a jump?
Does the code in listing 2 involve any vtable lookup at all?

I understand that these may be compiler dependent, and perhaps the standard will not specify the implementation details. In that case, I would be grateful if someone who understands how GCC or CLANG handles these cases provides for an explanation.

Thanks.

EDIT: Please cut-paste your assembler output; I am still not sure why in 2nd case there should be any lookup in vtable.

Comment: Have you tried disassembling the generated code?

Comment: The first simple answer is that you are leaking objects, so you might want to rewrite the example in a way that makes a bit more sense. That will also affect the possible answers, as depending on how much visibility the compiler has, it might be able (or not) to optimize the call to avoid dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @Fanatic - You can ask yourself: "Is this coding style common enough that the compiler writer will invest in optimizing it?". My guess is: Probably not, unless the info just happens to be produced by some other analysis.

Answer (score 3):

From the wiki:

> The C++ standards do not mandate exactly how dynamic dispatch must be implemented, but compilers generally use minor variations on the same basic model. Typically, the compiler creates a separate vtable for each class.

the compiler will create a vtable for every class that contains `virtual` functions, as stated [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/):

> every class that uses virtual functions (or is derived from a class that uses virtual functions) is given it’s own virtual table. This table is simply a static array that the compiler sets up at compile time. A virtual table contains one entry for each virtual function that can be called by objects of the class. Each entry in this table is simply a function pointer that points to the most-derived function accessible by that class.

Answer (score 2):

It is a virtual method call. There must be and there is a vtable look-up at runtime in both cases.

The compiler cannot know whether something happened in between the call to the constructor and the call to the function, which might have modified b and d and changed their actual type to be something else.

What the standard says:

> 2 If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a
>   class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member
>   function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), and
>   cv-qualification as Base::vf is declared, then Derived::vf is also
>   virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides
>   Base::vf. For
>   convenience we say that any virtual function overrides itself. Then in
>   any well-formed class, for each virtual function declared in that
>   class or any of its direct or indirect base classes there is a unique
>   final overrider that overrides that function and every other overrider
>   of that function. The rules for member lookup (10.2) are used to
>   determine the final overrider for a virtual function in the scope of a
>   derived class but ignoring names introduced by using-declarations.
>
> 7 [ Note: the interpretation of the call of a virtual function depends
>   on the type of the object for which it is called (the dynamic type),
>   whereas the interpretation of a call of a non-virtual member function
>   depends only on the type of the pointer or reference denoting that
>   object (the static type) (5.2.2). —end note ]

This does not mandate how it is done, but states pretty much clearly that the call must be resolved on the actual type of the object when the call is placed.

Comment: The Standard never prohibits a sufficiently intelligent optimizer from doing anything, if the observable results are the same.  In this example, where the virtual function calls immediately follow the constructor calls, optimizing would be valid (though it looks like g++ -O9 does not).  (Also, the Standard doesn't even say that there must be any vtables at all.)

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to use a vtable. Only good or really clever compilers would optimize it out.

Look in the assembler result of your compiler to know the answer. Most of the time (if not all the time) there is a vtable access.

Comment: I don't think you can optimize it out. Any ideas on which case the compiler can optimize it out?

Comment: I think if the class is the class who has declared the virtual function (so no inherited classes) and if there is no "real" code between construction of the class and access of the method the access can be optimized. But be aware, a assembler access with or without mutable would broke all optimization, because everything could happen to the object outside of c++. Currently I don't know any compiler who could do this, maybe GCC? CLang?

Comment: @Chip: If the compiler sees that code inside a function, it *knows* that the actual object in both cases is of type `D`, so it *could* potentially use static dispatch to the final overrider.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas in the above example, how do you (the compiler) know that new is not overloaded to return something other than D?

Comment: @Chip: Simply because you cannot. The `new` in the code is an expression that gets transformed by the compiler into a call to `operator new` (which can be overloaded by the user) and then placement new to call the constructor. The constructor called is the constructor of `D`, and there is no way of changing that behavior.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yes.. you are right.. I realize we cannot overload the constructor. So in this case, we can optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are calling `f()` on an object of a class that declared that function `virtual`, so the program must do vtable lookup to find the correct derived class's override of `f()` (unless in the trivial example in your post allows the compiler to optimize this out, knowing the exact class)

In the second case, there is no vtable lookup unless `D` declares `f()f` as virtual as well -- by knowing the class id `D`, the compiler knows which `f()` to call at compilation time.

Update (based on comments): The second case is equivalent to the first one as `D`'s overriding function is also virtual by virtue of `B` declaring it virtual (I've learnt something new today too :))

Comment: in C++ f() in D is automatically virtual. No way to declare it anything but virtual().

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek - Can you give me a reference for this?

Comment: @Chip how would you make it non-virtual?

Comment: C++2003, §10.3/2: "If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or
indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name and same parameter list as `Base::vf` is
declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (**whether or not it is so declared**) and it *overrides*
`Base::vf`."

Comment: Just don't specify "virtual" before the "base" function. @Seth : Note for Rob's answer, the member has to be declared "virtual" in the base class.

Comment: @Chip yes obviously. Christopher Oezbek said "in C++ f() in D is automatically virtual" because in the question, the OP says "Given a base class B with a virtual function f..."

Comment: @SethCarnegie I See.. sorry for the confusion.. I will delete my "confusing" comments.

Answer (score 0):

The VTable has to be looked up in both cases, as at compile-time, the code has no idea which function to call.

As all instructions are generated at compile time, a virtual function call will be translated into v-table lookup and then a jump.